# Destructuring when property name can vary

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Learning destructuring and facing problem with this situation. I have this structure -

```
myObj{
  key1: {prop1: true, prop2: false},
  key2: {prop1: false, prop2: false}
}
```

MyObj can have multiple keys whose names are set dynamically but all those are having same set of properties, say prop1 and prop2. I want to destructure to get prop1 and prop2 without knowing real name of key1 or key2.

```
const { prop1, prop2 } = myObj[someVar];  // someVar can be key1 or key2
```

Comment: " without knowing real name of key1 or key2" how would you pick a name then? In your example why `key1` not `key2`?

Comment: I updated comment a bit.

Comment: So what's the problem? Your code works, as long as `someVar` has the value "key1" or "key2"...

Comment: It does work. Previously I was using it inside redux-form component and my conditional statement was going wrong. I am updating my answer and solution to address it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I accepted kiranvj's solution but later realized following format is not wrong as well,

```
myObj[someVar].prop1; // or myObj[someVar].prop2;
   // or
const { prop1, prop2 } = myObj[someVar];
```

Wrong thing I was doing was with inline if statement, later creating with prop1 and prop2. That was not giving correct result. And I thought I am not destructuring it right. Adding conditional statements as well. (Though not directly related to post but adding extra information for react-newbies like me.)

```
// this failed to give result   
 { prop1 &&
    ((prop2 && <div>{allTrue}</div>))}

// simplified version gives correct result
{ prop1 && prop2 && <div>{allTrue}</div> }
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is this, if this is not what you want please comment, I will delete it

```js
let myObj = {
  key1: {prop1: true, prop2: false},
  key2: {prop1: false, prop2: false}
}

Object.values(myObj).forEach((item)=>{

  const {prop1, prop2} = item;
 
  console.log('prop1: ', prop1 );
  console.log('prop2: ', prop2 );
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the question has already been answered sufficiently, but I wanted to add some advice on this.

Unless you're working with a strongly typed version of JavaScript (e.g., Elm or TypeScript), I think it's a really bad idea to destructure an object's nested properties because it would produce type errors if the base property didn't exist beforehand (`key1`). This would potentially cause the app to fail.

If you're working in a strongly typed version of JavaScript, then the type enforcement would potentially error out at compile-time instead of run-time.

Single-layered destructuring is fine in my opinion though, because the worst that can happen is the assigned variable would become `undefined`.